# Trying to implement encryption methods using RSA in .NET?

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption, rsa

But I'm getting this error:

**an object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property rsa**

```
    public string FingerPrint
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] bytes = Utility.GetBytes(Imagin.FingerPrint.CPUId);
            byte[] encrypted_bytes = this.Encrypt(bytes, RSA.ExportParameters(false), false);
            return Utility.GetString(encrypted_bytes);
        }
    }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] encryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKey); encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return encryptedData;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] Data, RSAParameters RSAKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] decryptedData;
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                RSA.ImportParameters(RSAKey);
                decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(Data, DoOAEPPadding);
            }
            return decryptedData;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I read on another post that it's because I need to use a new instance of an object with this: `RSA.ExportParameters(false)`. An instance of what? I tried placing the code for getting `FingerPrint` in my MainWindow constructor, but no luck there either. If I make `FingerPrint` static, it just produces more issues.

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: You need to specify *where* you get that error message.

Comment: You probably need a `using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())` in that property there, to create a variable `RSA` that holds a reference. Then you probably need to import the parameters of a key as well, otherwise, what do you want it to export?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I get it at this line: `RSA.ExportParameters(false)`. That's the only line it highlights.

Comment: You have a variable named RSA. RSA is also the name of a .NET class. Change the name of your variable to be something else.